# How to add a section after a section containing multiple canvasses?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to build a HTML page which contains two canvasses, one is the background, other is the logo positioned on top of background. I placed them inside a *section* and appended the body with another *section* which contains other HTML content, but the next section is appended at the top of the HTML page instead of the preceding section.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
  html,body,canvas{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section style="position:relative;">
    <canvas id="bg" style="position:absolute;background-color:black;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="logo" style="position:absolute;background-color:blue;"></canvas>
  </section>
  <section style="position:absolute;color:white;">
    some text
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

`some text` appears on top of page, and stays independent of `position` property of its section.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set something to `position:absolute`, it gets kind of "detached" and can move around, so its parent becomes like empty, so it collapses to no height.

Keep the background in `position:relative`, so it gives a height to the section.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
}

#bg {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #008000;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <canvas id="bg"></canvas>
    <canvas id="logo"></canvas>
</section>

<section>
    some text
</section>
```

Comment: I'm aware of that but it didn't work this time. Please read the last statement of the question. I've mentioned it.

Comment: `bg` doesn't have a `position:absolute` property and so it worked. Would you be so kind to explain? btw, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Well, exactly as I said : When you set something to position:absolute, it gets kind of "detached" and can move around, so its parent becomes like empty, so it collapses to no height.